# Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Cache' not found in magento2 installation

Tags: magento2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Cache' not found in /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php:148 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array) #1 /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize() #2 /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/FrontendPool.php(84): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get('default') #3 /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/Config.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool->get('config') #4 /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config->_getFrontend() #5 /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(66): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->load('global::DiConfi...') #6 /var/www/h in /var/www/html/stdcw/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php on line 148

Answer (score -1):

It seems cache issue, Clear your all cache which you have installed on your server like APC, MemCached.

if it still give an issue then the problem is in improper installation of Magento2 instance.  Install new Magento 2 install with same version you have installed with Separate DB. Hope it helps.